# Python : Add a progress bar in a YouTube upload code

Tags: python, youtube

I have been working on a script that helps me automate the process of uploading VODs from local drive to YouTube.
Right now I only have a feedback when starting the upload, finishing the upload and when the upload fails.

I would like to add a progress bar to know how far in the upload I am, with a few data like Mo uploaded / Mo left to upload...

Here is my code, I have tried different ways to add a progress bar but nothing works.
I'm running the code with a bat file.

The code is clearly not clean at all, I used some help from GPT for the chunk manager, it's a work in progress that needs some improving, but it works great!

````
import os
import webbrowser
import re
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors
import pickle
import shutil
import time
import requests

WEBHOOK_URL = "xxxx"


def authenticate_youtube():
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secrets.json"
    
    token_filename = "youtube_token.pickle"
    credentials = load_token(token_filename)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(googleapiclient.errors.Request())
        else:
            flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"])
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            save_token(credentials, token_filename)
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    
    return youtube

def save_token(credentials, token_file):
    with open(token_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(credentials, token)

def load_token(token_file):
    if os.path.exists(token_file):
        with open(token_file, 'rb') as token:
            return pickle.load(token)
    return None

def format_title(filename):
    # Match the original format
    match = re.search(r"Stream - (\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}) - (\d{2}h\d{2})", filename)
    if match:
        year, month, day, time = match.groups()
        sanitized_title = f"VOD | Stream du {day} {month} {year}"
    else:
        # Match the new format
        match = re.search(r"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})", filename)
        if match:
            year, month, day, hour, minute, second = match.groups()
            sanitized_title = f"VOD | Stream du {day} {month} {year}"
        else:
            sanitized_title = filename

    # Sanitize the filename
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\-_\. ]', '_', sanitized_title)


def send_discord_webhook(message):
    data = {"content": message}
    response = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, json=data)
    if response.status_code != 204:
        print(f"Webhook call failed: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
   

def upload_video(youtube, file_path):
    print(f" -> Detected file: {file_path}")
    title = format_title(os.path.basename(file_path)).replace("_", "|").replace(".mkv", "")
    print(f" * Uploading : {title}...")
    send_discord_webhook(f'- Uploading : {title}')
    
    # Load predefined tags from the file
    tags_file_path = "tags.txt"
    with open(tags_file_path, 'r') as tags_file:
        tags = tags_file.read().splitlines()
        
        
    description = (
    "⏬ Déroule-moi ! ⏬\n"
    f"VOD HD d'un stream Twitch de Ben_OnAir uploadée automatiquement\n\n"
    "═════════════════════\n\n"
    "► Je stream ici : https://www.twitch.tv/ben_onair\n"
    "► Ma Chaîne Youtube : https://www.youtube.com/@BenOnAir\n"
    "► Mon Twitter : https://twitter.com/Ben_OnAir\n"
    "► Mon Insta : https://www.instagram.com/ben_onair/\n"
    "► Mon Book : https://ben-book.fr/"
    )
    
    # Setup request for resumable upload
    request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part="snippet,status",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "categoryId": "20",
                "description": description,
                "title": title,
                "tags": tags
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        },
        media_body=googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload(file_path, resumable=True, chunksize=-1)
    )

    response = None
    while response is None:
        try:
            status, response = request.next_chunk()
            if response is not None:
                if 'id' in response:
                    video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={response['id']}"
                    print(f" -> Uploaded {file_path} with video ID {response['id']} - {video_url}")
                    send_discord_webhook(f'- Uploaded : {title} | {video_url}')
                    webbrowser.open(video_url, new=2)
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to upload {file_path}. No video ID returned from YouTube.")
                    end_discord_webhook(f'- Failed uploading : {title}')
        except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
            print(f"An HTTP error {e.resp.status} occurred while uploading {file_path}: {e.content}")
            break
            # You can handle specific HTTP error codes here if needed


def main(directory_path):
    youtube = authenticate_youtube()
    files = [os.path.join(directory_path, f) for f in os.listdir(directory_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory_path, f))]
    for file_path in files:
        upload_video(youtube, file_path)
        # Move the local video file to a different directory after upload
        print(f" * Moving local file: {file_path}")
        shutil.move(file_path, "M:\\VOD UPLOADED")
        print(f" -> Moved local file: {file_path}")

try:
    main("M:\\VOD TO UPLOAD")
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
    print(f" -> Quota Exceeded!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f" -> An error occured : {e}")
    send_discord_webhook(f'-> An error occured : {e}')```
````

Comment: Someone may write a more thorough reply, but as a quick hint, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for using threading, which would allow your code to switch back and forth between different functionality. So you can have a progress bar updating in "parallel" to your main code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in how to display the progress bar in the terminal, you can do this by printing a progress bar consisting of ascii chars (like `[######............]` for example) and jump to the begin of the line using `\r` char whenever you update it.

So, you gotta decide for `bar_length` defining the length in characters and then do something like that:

```
done_length = (progress_done / progress_total) * bar_length
print(
  "\r["
  + "#" * done_length
  + "." * (bar_length - done_length)
  + "]"
)
```

Then you need obtain your `progress_done` and `progress_total` values. For example, if your video has a size of 500 MB, and 120 MB are already uploaded, set `progress_total` to 500 and `progress_done`to 120.

If your question was how to obtain those values, I think I can't really help you with that.

It looks like you're using a while loop to just wait for the upload to be done. That doesn't provide any information about how much of the video is already uploaded, it just waits for a response.

You could check if the Google API can give you that information, or if some of the librarys you use are able to check how much of your file was already sent.

Maybe you should give some more specific information about how the requests are sent in your code and which library is used for what purpose. Also consider taking a look at the documentations.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was planning to do, however I don't have any clue about how to check how many MB where uploaded out of the total MB

Comment: @Ben_OnAir, you can use tqdm. I did it in one of my GitHub repo: https://github.com/timotheeMM/cli-youtube-downloader/blob/main/src/main.py. You have to see if the youtube API accepts the callback function when downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaUploadProgress-class.html) and [source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/googleapiclient/http.py), it looks like your `status` variable should be a `MediaUploadProgress` object. `status.resumable_progress` should be the bytes sent so far and `status.total_size` should be the total size.

You can then use that with any number of progress bar libraries to display a progress bar. I would recommend [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) because it natively supports printing without messing up the progress bars, so you don't have to make any changes to your print statements like you would with some of the other libraries.